# Delete cached images from folder

Tags: android, android-activity

I currently save images that I download from the internet to disk. I want to be able to delete the images when the user closes the app. I want the images all saved in one folder so it will be easy to delete them.  I did `getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "newfoldername"`  to get a path to a folder. Not sure how to add the images into the folder.

```
public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b, String name_file, String path) {
    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = context.openFileOutput(name_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap getImageBitmap(Context context, String name) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize =  1;
        Bitmap  b =   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis,null, options);
        b.getAllocationByteCount());
        fis.close();
        return b;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't save the images on your cache folder as you can't rely on it as per the documentation. A better approach would be to store them on your SD Card. As per the documentation :

```
public abstract File getCacheDir()
```

**Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem. These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs low on storage. There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted. Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space.**

**FOR SAVING**

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    File directory = getApplicationContext().getDir("MY_IMAGE_FOLDER"
    ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

**FOR READING**

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{
    try {
        File file = new File(path, "Image.jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_imgView);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**FOR DELETING :**

```
String dir = getApplicationContext().getDir("MY_IMAGE_FOLDER"
    ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AndroidWarrior- how can i read these images? and how can i deleted the folder when the app closes.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior- like getting a Bitmap from the saved image so i can display it

Comment: @AndroidWarrior- also i want the images private. So that they cant be found using a file manager

Comment: @AndroidWarrior-Thanks a lot :)